# Examine function differentiability

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

How to examine differentiability of the function $$y+\cos{\sqrt[3]{(x^2+y^2)}}$$ at $$(0,0)$$?

Partial derivatives are not defined there. The differential of the function equals to $$1-\frac{2}{3}\frac{(x+y)\sin((x^2+y^2)^{(1/3)}))}{(x^2+y^2)^{(2/3)}}$$. What should I do to come to a conclusion on differentiability?

Comment: The differential of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is *not* differentiable at $(0,0)$. If it was, the function $x\mapsto0+\cos\left(\sqrt[3]{x^2}\right)$ would be differentiable at $0$. But it is not.

Comment: Could you give a hint on how to prove the connection?

Comment: A hint? I will give you the full answer: if you compose two differntiable functions, then what you get is again a differentable function. And the function $x\mapsto(x,0)$ *is* differentiable.